# (Javascript) Accessing the last element from a list in the Firebase RealtimeDatabase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've encountered a problem I don't know the solution to.
In the Firebase RealtimeDatabase, I created a List of Strings via `ref.push();`
Now I need to access later the last object I created via `ref.push();`.
Because I need to access it in another instance, I can't get the key of the new reference directly from the function.

What would be the proper way to retreive the last Item of such a list?
I fiddled around with various ways (i.e. accessing if like a normal array, and then grabbing the last element of that array), but nothing worked so far.

I would be really glad if someone could help me out with that.

EDIT:

The relevant part of the database looks like this:

[image: relevant_part]

I created the list in another function through calls of

```
var newRef = admin.database().ref(`PATH/TO/LIST`).push();
newRef.set("someString");
```

And because I generated the items of the earlier, I can't just pass `newRef` to the function I need it in to access the item.

Comment: Can you add to your post more info on 1/ Your database structure 2/ The exact code you are using (i.e. what's "around" the `ref.push();`)

Comment: If you know the path to the list you can use [limit queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#limit-queries) to get the last one.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? I found varying ways online but no "Best-practise"-like solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as follows:

```
firebase.database().ref('PATH/TO/LIST').limitToLast(1).once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
         console.log(childSnapshot.val());
     });
});
```

Two points to note:

1. "The unique key generated by push() are ordered by the current time, so the resulting list of items will be chronologically sorted" as explained in the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push. So your items are sorted chronologically.
2. You have to loop over the result of the once because the `limitToLast()` method is used when constructing a `query` which always return a "set of records" (i.e. `DataSnapshot`s for the subset of the data that matches your query), even if the result of the query is only one item.

---

Edit following your comment:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('PATH/TO/LIST');

ref.limitToLast(1).once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
    var itemKey;
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       itemKey = childSnapshot.key;
       console.log(itemKey);
    });

    return ref.child(itemKey).set('someString3NEW');

})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

You get the key of the node you want to change (with the same query as above) and you use the `set()` method to change it's value.

Comment: Okay, and if I need to change the actual value of that String? Let's say I want to change "someString3" to "someString3NEW".

How to set that value in the database without knowing the reference?

Comment: Perfect, that worked very well. Now that I see it, it doesn't seem that hard, but somehow I got confused.
Anyways, Thank you very much!